# Как упростить однообразные скрипты?

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '#modal_btn1', function(){
        $('#small-modal').arcticmodal();
        $('#tovar').val('<?php echo "$aw1_name"; ?>');
        $('#model-name').html('<?php echo "$aw1_name"; ?> <span><?php echo $nombre_format_francais = number_format($aw1_price, 0, '.', ' '); ?></span>');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#modal_btn2', function(){
        $('#small-modal').arcticmodal();
        $('#tovar').val('<?php echo "$aw2_name"; ?>');
        $('#model-name').html('<?php echo "$aw2_name"; ?> <span><?php echo $nombre_format_francais = number_format($aw2_price, 0, '.', ' '); ?></span>');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#modal_btn3', function(){
        $('#small-modal').arcticmodal();
        $('#tovar').val('<?php echo "$aw3_name"; ?>');
        $('#model-name').html('<?php echo "$aw3_name"; ?> <span><?php echo $nombre_format_francais = number_format($aw3_price, 0, '.', ' '); ?></span>');
    });
```

при клике на кнопку появляется модальное окно, параллельно подставляется значение (val и html) в соответствующие поля. Таких однообразных скриптов приходится вставлять на страницу более 60 штук, чтобы все работало. Может есть какой-нибудь способ заменить эти 60 команд одним скриптом, более простым?

Пробовал сделать через .attr("id") , но знаний не хватает.

Comment: Если у вас определено, что номера идут последовательно, то сделайте цикл от 1 до N и вставьте переменную в те места, где надо........ а если понять логику вывода `aw1_name/aw2_name/awN_name` ...... то можно вообще без цикла обойтись, лишь присвоив кнопкам общий класс `.modalBtn` и делать `$(document).on('click', '.modalBtn', function(){ ...`....... а если еще не делать `aw1_name/aw2_name/awN_name` а сделать по клику на кнопке загрузку аякс нужного контента в данный конкретный момент времени, то еще лучше будет

Comment: покажите, как вы выводите разметку кнопок `<button id="#modal-btn1"...`

Comment: @Sergiks <button id="modal_btn1">Купить</button>

Comment: Набросил пару вариантов. Конечно интересно как в принципе эти вьюхи выглядят .

Comment: @Alexander обновил ответ – прямо при выводе кнопок вкладывайте в них самих через HTML5 data-атрибуты название, цену и id.

Answer (score 2):

Я б предложил следующее:

делаем кнопки с одним классом, например `modal-btn`, добавляем каждой кнопке атрибут `data-id`, чтобы иметь различия между ними.

При клике, отправляем запрос к серваку. Он в зависимости от нажатой кнопке генерит нужные данные и возвращает на клиент. Клиент уже эти данные вставляет в нужные поля.

Примерно так...
Файл сервера, который генерит ответ:

```
echo json_encode(array('name' => 'myNameNumber'.$_POST['id'], 'price' => number_format(rand(5, 15), 0, '.', ' ')));
```

файл клиента:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.modal-btn', function(){ 
    $.post( "myServerFile.php", {id: $(this).data('id')},  function( data ) {
 $('#small-modal').arcticmodal();
 $('#tovar').val(data.name);
 $('#model-name').html(data.name + ', <span>' + data.price + '</span>');
    }, "json"); 
});
```

```html
<input type="button" data-id="1" class="modal-btn" value="go 1">
<input type="button" data-id="2" class="modal-btn" value="go 2">
<input type="button" data-id="3" class="modal-btn" value="go 3">
<br /><br />

Товар: <input id="tovar"><br/>
Модель с ценой: <span id="model-name"></span>
```

Теперь при клике на любую кнопку будет передаваться её идентификатор в запрос, на сервере в зависимости от кнопки производятся какие-либо действия и затем ответ парсится.

---

Т.к. каждый раз при клике на кнопку вызывать аякс немного накладно, то есть другой вариант:

При загрузке страницы обратиться к серверу и взять все нужные данные

js

```
var myData =  null;

$.post( "get.php", {id: $(this).data('id')},  function( data ) {
    myData = data;
}, "json");
```

php

```
echo json_encode(array( 
    array('name' => 'myNameNumber1', 'price' => number_format(rand(5, 15), 0, '.', ' ')),
    array('name' => 'myNameNumber2', 'price' => number_format(rand(5, 15), 0, '.', ' '))
    array('name' => 'myNameNumber3', 'price' => number_format(rand(5, 15), 0, '.', ' '))
    )
);
```

А затем при клике на любую кнопку брать уже данные из этого полученного массива, по его идентификатору.
Что-то типа:

```
$(document).on('click', '.modal-btn', function(){       
    var info = myData[$(this).data('id')];

    $('#small-modal').arcticmodal();
    $('#tovar').val(info.data.name);
    $('#model-name').html(info.data.name + ', <span>' + info.data.price + '</span>');
});
```

Comment: Всё здраво, кроме ajax'а к серверу по нажатию на кнопку – это увеличивает время реакции интерфейса на действие пользователя. В данной ситуации не оправданно, imho.

Comment: @Sergiks согласен. подзагруз будет..... добавил еще вариант

Answer (score 2):

Сервер, во время генерации кнопок, пускай в них же вкладывает данные для popup через [data-атрибуты](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) html5:

```
<?php
function btnHtml( $name, $price) {
    static $id = 0; // счётчик для кнопок
    $id++;
    return sprintf(
        '<button class="modal_btn"
            id="modal_btn%d"
            data-id="%d"
            data-name="%s"
            data-price="%s"
        >Купить</button>'
        ,$id
        ,$id
        ,$name
        ,number_format($price, 0, '.', ' ')
    );
}

echo btnHtml( $aw1_name, $aw1_price);
echo btnHtml( $aw2_name, $aw2_price);
echo btnHtml( $aw3_name, $aw3_price);
```

А на клиенте слушать события всех кнопок этого класса, и брать данные прямо из них же методом jQuery [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/#jQuery-data2):

```
$(document).on('click', ".modal_btn", function(){
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var html = '' + name + ' ' + '<span>' + $(this).data('price') + '</span>';
    $('#small-modal').arcticmodal();
    $('#tovar').val( name);
    $('#model-name').html( html);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Схема примерно такая:

```
function doIt(name, price) {
        $('#small-modal').arcticmodal();
        $('#tovar').val(name);
        $('#model-name').html(name + ' <span>' + price + '</span>');
}

var buttons = [
    { id: 'modal_btn1', name: '<?php echo "$aw1_name"; ?>', price: '<?php echo $nombre_format_francais = number_format($aw1_price, 0, '.', ' '); ?>' }, ...
];

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  var button = buttons[i];
  $(document).on('click', '#' + button.id, function(){ doIt(button.name, button.price) });
}
```

Comment: если вы не заметили, то тут смешан php код и js, поэтому ваш вариант не будет работать, и к тому же не заменили строку _<?php echo "$aw3_name"; ?>_

Comment: поправил. то, что код php вставлен, удивило, но раз уж так надо автору...

Comment: так как пхп код исполняется на сервер, а яваскрипт на клиенте, вы не можете использовать клиентскую переменную `name` для вывода через php

Comment: Спасибо за вариант. К сожалению, не работает. Вероятно, из-за php.

Comment: Исправил еще раз, чтобы php нормально отрабатывал. Так более громоздко конечно, но должно работать. Дальнейшие упрощения уже должны быть на стороне php

Comment: Спасибо. почти работает) Но почему-то при клике на modal_btn1 выводит значения modal_btn2 (пробовал 2), если Вы понимаете о чем я.

Comment: Проверьте массив buttons, там все значения должны соответствовать друг другу, возможно у вас в объекте с id равным modal_btn1 записаны данные для modal_btn2

Comment: Проверил. Все четко: { id: 'modal_btn1', name: '<?php echo "$aw1_name"; ?>', price: '<?php echo $nombre_format_francais = number_format($aw1_price, 0, '.', ' '); ?> грн.' }, { id: 'modal_btn2', name: '<?php echo "$aw2_name"; ?>', price: '<?php echo $nombre_format_francais = number_format($aw2_price, 0, '.', ' '); ?> грн.' }            Добавлял третью кнопку - при клике на любую выводит значение третей...

Comment: Исправил пару опечаток. может в это дело было. Но вообще конечно тот, кто ответил после, прав, тут нужно править серверную часть, чтобы вообще все красиво было. Я, к сожалению, тут помочь не могу, в php не силен.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).